# android:autoMirrored not working on vector drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

Why does my vector drawable refuse to mirror itself when a RTL language is set on my device? I already checked the **Enable auto mirroring for RTL layout** box but this isn't working for some reason.

**Current result (English)**

[image]

**Expected result (Hebrew)**

[image]

**Current result (Hebrew)**

[image]

**Drawable XML**

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp" android:viewportWidth="24" android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M12,4l-1.41,1.41L16.17,11H4v2h12.17l-5.58,5.59L12,20l8,-8z"/>
</vector>
```

**Activity layout**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mTV = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTV)
        val appName = getString(R.string.app_name)
        val template = "$appName <img src=\"arrow\"/> $appName"
        mTV.text = Html.fromHtml(template, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, imageGetter, null)
    }

    private val imageGetter = Html.ImageGetter { name ->
        val resId = if (name == "arrow") R.drawable.ic_arrow
        else throw IllegalArgumentException("what the heck is $name")

        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, resId, theme)?.apply {
            setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out?

Comment: @pushandpop unfortunately not yet, no